# What SSLCipherSuite should I use to remove these Suites?

Tags: apache-2.4, tls

My current commands:

```
SSLProtocol -ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS:!RC4
```

When I run SSLScan however I am getting that the following Ciphers are still available:

```
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  168 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  168 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
```

How can I modify my SSLCipherSuite command to remove support for these?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the oldest client you need to support?

Comment: I'm trying to disable the ciphers listed above. I don't need to support any particular client in the sense that if it is so old as to only accept the above ciphers, than the client will be issued instructions to move to a more modern one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For working through this sort of situation, I recommend using the `openssl ciphers` command-line tool, *e.g.*:

```
openssl ciphers -v 'RSA+AES' | sort
```

which will list the individual cipher suites for that OpenSSL cipher name; the `-v` command-line option provide more information (such as the protocol version for that ciphersuite), and makes the output format more like the `SSLScan` output.  The use of `sort` is optional; I personally find it easier to search for names, such as the ones you provided, using a sorted list.

I recommend using single quotes around the cipher name, so that it is not interpreted by the shell.  Note that using protocol versions also works, *e.g.*:

```
openssl ciphers 'TLSv1.2'
```

Using this approach, and going through the protocol versions *and* cipher names, we find that the culprits are `DH+AES256`, which provides:

```
openssl ciphers -v `DH+AES256`
...
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
...
```

Another culprit is `DH+AES`:

```
openssl ciphers -v 'DH+AES' | sort
...
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
...
```

And there's `DH+3DES`, which provides:

```
openssl ciphers -v 'DH+3DES' | sort
...
EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
...
```

The `RSA+AES` name provides *two* of your undesired ciphersuites:

```
openssl ciphers -v 'RSA+AES' | sort
...
AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
...
AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
...
```

And last, there's `RSA+3DES`:

```
openssl ciphers -v 'RSA+3DES' | sort
...
DES-CBC3-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
```

So, you *could* remove all of the guilty names mentioned from your `SSLCipherSuite` directive, as long as there'd be enough remaining supported ciphersuites for your clients.

Hope this helps!